# Extract specific values from multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, higher-order-functions

I have a multidimensional array seen below. I wish extract all the `ingredients` values from it, and then do an action with them, like count how many of each there are.

```
var products = [
{ name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
{ name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
{ name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
{ name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
{ name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
];
```

I have done this using a function from Underscore.js, `_.flatten()`, and the vanilla javascript function `map()`, but I had to use `map()` twice. Once for extracting all the ingredients, and then to make a hash style structure that counts up the number of times each ingredient occurs. I store these counts in a separate object, `ingredientCount` in this case.

```
var ingredientCount = {};
_.flatten(products.map(function(x) {
    return x.ingredients;
})).map(function(y){
    return ingredientCount[y] = (ingredientCount[y] || 0) + 1;
});
```

`console.log(ingredientCount);` will output the following list:

```
{ artichoke: 1,
  'sundried tomatoes': 2,
  mushrooms: 2,
  roma: 1,
  'goats cheese': 1,
  rosemary: 1,
  'black beans': 1,
  jalapenos: 1,
  'blue cheese': 1,
  garlic: 1,
  walnuts: 1,
  spinach: 1,
  'kalamata olives': 1,
  'sesame seeds': 1 }
```

I have solved my problem, but I feel like there should be a cleaner, more efficient way to do this without using `map()` twice. Can anyone help me out? I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: This is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This is the most elegant way I can think of in plain JavaScript, as it doesn't use any intermediary data structures (the original solution creates two arrays which are then combined into the final object).

```
var counts = products.reduce(function (result, product) {
    product.ingredients.forEach(function (ingredient) {
        result[ingredient] = (result[ingredient] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: Why don't you `reduce` over the `.ingredients` as well?

Comment: `reduce` implies creating a data structure, and granted you don't need to but it will still be passing along values between calls, which I don't need to at that step since we only want the ingredient count across all products. So in the end I'd just be using `reduce` for iterating the list, which `forEach` is much more suited for.

Comment: Well, you're not creating the object `{}` either during the outer iteration - but if you choose to pass it along, you should pass it trough both loops for consistency. Or through neither (`var counts = {}; products.forEach(…)`).

Comment: I'd rather use `forEach` for both then because using `reduce` twice with the same "previous" value doesn't make logical sense.

Here's how I express my solution in words: "Merge all the products into one value (the sum), and do so by looping through and counting each ingredient." Essentially, this is a map/reduce operation, but since I don't need to transform the values I chose to use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: Well, what doesn't make sense is that we are mutating the value, when we try to think functional :-) Btw, it could be a `flatMap`/`reduce` operation :-)

Comment: I can definitely see the argument in regards to mutating vs. functional, hence why I'd rather go to using simply forEach on a passed-in value. :) It could be a `flatMap` I suppose, but since that doesn't exist in JavaScript by default it'd be overkill to implement such a function. I guess by calling `_.flatten(list.map).map`, OP is essentially doing just that, but it's bound to be less performant and doesn't read better in this case (IMO).

Comment: I guess the best-looking thing would be `_(products).pluck("ingredients").flatten().reduce(countBy, {})`

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion:

```js
var products = [
{ name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
{ name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
{ name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
{ name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
{ name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
];    

// written by hand, with <3
function ic(p,o,i,b,g) {
  i|=0;g|=0;
  if(!b&&p&&!p.ingredients)
    while((g=ic(p[g].ingredients,o,0,g+1))&&p[g]);
  else {
    o[p[i]]=(o[p[i]]|0)+1;
    return p[i+1]?ic(p,o,i+1,b):b;
  }
}
    
var ingredientCount = {};
ic(products, ingredientCount);

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ingredientCount).replace(/(\,)/g,"$1<br/>");
```

```css
body {font-family: monospace }
```

```html
<body></body>
```

**EDIT: No i'm not serious. [But its almost 3x faster](http://jsperf.com/ingredient-count)**

Comment: Not serious? [16 times faster than that](http://jsperf.com/ingredient-count/3). And unmeasurably simpler :-)

Comment: Ah damn, I shouldn't have deleted my "plain loops would be faster" comment. I pledge guilty of providing this answer for its own sake ;)